# Log text in mlflow

Tags: mlflow, mlops

I know that you can log metrics as your experiment progresses. For example the training loss over epochs for your DL model.

I was wondering if it was possible to do something similar for text. In my particular case I have a text model that generates some example text after each epoch and I wish to see what it's like. For example:

```
Epoch 1:
tHi is RubisH
Epoch 2:
Ok look slight better
Epoch 3:
I can speak English better than William Shakespeare
```

The workaround I can think of is to log this to a text file and push that as an artifact in mlflow. Was wondering if there was something else more native to mlflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [log_param/log_params](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.log_param) for that. For long texts maybe it's better to use [log_text](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.log_text) instead...

Comment: Would this log it (the second epoch etc.) in a new line if I use the same filename?

Comment: No, if you look into the source code, you'll see that it always overwrite the content: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/tracking/client.py#L967